# UWP App. upgrade from VS 16.7 to VS 16.10 and got this error: MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper' threw an exception

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2019

i have been searching a solution for many hours now, i see posts with similar text, however, still cannot find a solution to the error i am seeing.
My App was working before i upgraded visual studio 2019 from version 16.7 to version 16.10.
i am getting following error:

```
  System.TypeInitializationException
  HResult=0x80131534
  Message=The type initializer for 'MongoDB.Driver.Core.Misc.DnsClientWrapper' threw an exception.
  Source=MongoDB.Driver
  StackTrace:
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrlBuilder.Parse(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoUrl..ctor(String url)
   at MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient..ctor(String connectionString)
   

Inner Exception 1:
AggregateException: Error resolving name servers (Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)) 
(Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040))

Inner Exception 2:
FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

any help will be really appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: I was experiencing the same issue and it was because I had updated the DnsClient package to 1.5, but MongoDB driver is looking for 1.4, so I had to put an assembly binding direct `oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.5.0.0" newVersion="1.5.0.0"` in the .config file